# A inexplicable thing about jquery call webservice

Tags: jquery, ajax, service, web

There are some different in IE10 and Chrome.

### The Code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onClick() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (json) { alert(json.d); },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error:" + error.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="onClick()" target="_blank"> CallBack</a>
</body>
</html>
```

---

When I browser the page in Chrome,it alert Error:,no error.responseTest,and go to google.com.
When I browser the page in IE10,it alert Hello World,and NOTHING.

Comment: Which do you want it to do? If you don't want to follow the link in Chrome add `return false;`. Also, do you have any errors in the console in IE? Any errors could cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: I want use webservice to count the link,when user click the link,count++,then go to the url.

Comment: Ok, then you're going about this the wrong way because it's likely that the AJAX won't finish since you're immediately going to another page. You should handle the increment and the redirect on the server side.

Comment: OK.But why the is different in IE10 and Chrome?

Comment: It's hard to say, but you're leaving the page while trying to do an AJAX call, so weird things will probably happen.

Comment: Thanks woz,but how to get the result:when I click the link,open it in new window and record the count?

Comment: What language are you using on the server? You are already using that to update the count; just find out how you can redirect the page right after that. AJAX is not necessary.